# Which of the two population does new measurement belongs to?

Tags: classification

I have a sample of size 150K from one population of measurements, and another sample of size 1000 from a second population. I receive a new measurement and need to decide which population it is coming from? given the huge difference between the sample sizes, what is the best method to decide which population the new measurement belongs to?

Comment: _One_ new observation? Can you specify [e.g., NORM(100, 15), EXP(rate 12)] or describe [e.g.,sample means, medians, quartiles, max's min's, SD's; boxplots, histograms] the populations from which the two large samples were taken?

Comment: Assume we don't know anything about the populations, and also the histogram of the two samples are very skewed, and don't match any know distributions.

Comment: If you have only one observation and the histograms have overlapping values: Find the modes of the two histograms and guess that single observation came from the population with the mode nearest to it.

Comment: Something to consider is how bad it is to classify something wrong. Is it worse to call an A a B than it is to call a B an A? (Say A is the group with 150k and B is the group with 1k.)

Answer (score 1):

So far, this seems to be an extremely vague question. Here is an experiment that might help
clarify the question. Are *your* histograms sufficiently different
for you to make reasonable choices? Mine are sufficiently different to 
allow good choices in some cases.

First, two histograms (made using R):

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
  x1 = rgamma(150000, 10, 1)
   hist(x1, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
  x2 = rexp(1000, 2)
   hist(x2, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

If the new single observation is 10.17, then pick the first population.
If the new value is 0.53, then pick the second population.

It is *possible,* but very unlikely, that 10.17 came from the distribution that resulted in the second histogram. It is *possible,*
but very unlikely, that 0.53 came from the distribution that resulted in the first histogram. So the choices in
the previous paragraph are reasonable.

Comment: Are you thinking of something like comparing likelihoods at 10.17? (To others reading this: likelihood has a technical meaning in statistics, which is what I mean.)

Comment: @Dave. Yes, but I have no clue that OP has seen a technical definition of _likelihood._ Trying to answer at appropriate level, and provoke a more focused question if possible.

Comment: It seems, then, that you are anticipating people will interpret "likely" in terms of probability: but how can you do that without positing a prior distribution for the two populations??  As an extreme case, suppose population `x1` is $10^9$ times more likely (*a priori*) to be the population: then even upon observing $0.53,$ the posterior odds are still around $7:1$ in favor of `x1`.

Comment: @whuber Meaning something along the lines of favoring one group 150:1 means that the likelihood of the smaller group should be 150 times greater for us to classify the observation as having come from the smaller group?

Comment: There happen to be more observations from one group than the other. Is it reasonable to infer that the group with more observations is more likely? You can have a larger sample from Montana than from New York. Unless otherwise stated, seems reasonable it's a 50:50 choice. // `dexp(.53,.2)/dgamma(.53,10,1)` returns 33,608,650.

Comment: Dave, the relevant concept here is ["Bayes Factor."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_factor)  It multiplies the prior odds (that the sample would come from one population vs. another) to give the posterior odds.  The important point is that one cannot even talk about that odds (or probability) until prior odds have been stipulated.  Bruce: your use of parameters is inconsistent: do you mean `.2` (as in your comment) or `2` (as in your answer) for the exponential scale parameter?

Comment: @whuber Wouldn't the Bayes Factor be 1/150?